# How do I get the number of ViewColumns the user has open from a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on developing a VSCode extension, and I open a webview using the following:

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
                'webviewName', // Identifies the type of the webview. Used internally
                'Webview Title', // Title of the panel displayed to the user
                vscode.ViewColumn.Two, // Editor column to show the new webview panel in.
                {} // Webview options.
            );
```

Note the `ViewColumn.Two` argument that is passed to it. This affects which view column the webview becomes a part of.

My intended behavior is for the webview is to ALWAYS open to the side. This means that if the user has one file open, then I can open it in ViewColumn 2. However, if they had two files open side-by-side, I'd need to open it in ViewColumn three, and so forth.

How do I get the number of ViewColumns in the current window from the VSCode API?

Also a note: The visual-studio-code-extensions tag does not exist. I want to create it but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for `vscode.ViewColumn.Beside`:

> A *symbolic* editor column representing the column to the side of the active one.

Comment: God I love this website. Took 4 months, but eventually I got a great answer to this quite esoteric question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get current column:

`vscode.window.activeTextEditor.viewColumn`